# It is impossible Debugging over Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, wear-os

Trying to debug an application on wear. Prior to this, using the emulator, we now have the device. Following the instructions, stopped on the line

In the Android Wear companion app, you should see the status change to:

Host: connected Target: connected

The phone status host: not connected target device is connected.

what could be the problem? I have a feeling that it is impossible to connect device.

P.s. USB debugging on my phone, and debugging via bluetooth on the clock included. App for my  phone (for my model LG G Watch), also downloaded and installed.

Comment: open USB debugging under Setting->Developer Options->USB debugging on your phone

Comment: I do it later, debugging is on

Comment: What I kept experiencing is I can never get target connected. I can logcat from adb fine that means I'm debugging using usb fine but Android Wear App doesn't think so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)Setup Devices for Debugging

Enable USB debugging on the handheld:

Open the Settings app and scroll to the bottom.

If it doesn't have a Developer Options setting, tap About Phone (or About Tablet), scroll to the bottom, and tap the build number 7 times.

Go back and tap Developer Options.

Enable USB debugging.

Enable Bluetooth debugging on the wearable:

Tap the home screen twice to bring up the Wear menu.

Scroll to the bottom and tap Settings.

Scroll to the bottom. If there's no Developer Options item, tap About, and then tap the 
build number 7 times.

Tap the Developer Options item.

Enable Debug over Bluetooth.

2)Set Up a Debugging Session

On the handheld, open the Android Wear companion app.

Tap the menu on the top right and select Settings.

Enable Debugging over Bluetooth. You should see a tiny status summary appear under the option:

```
    Host: disconnected

    Target: connected
```

Connect the handheld to your machine over USB and run:
adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub; adb connect localhost:4444

Note: You can use any available port that you have access to.

In the Android Wear companion app, you should see the status change to:

Host: connected

Target: connected

3)Debug Your App

Your wearable should show up as localhost:4444 when running adb devices. To run any adb command, use this format:

```
      adb -s localhost:4444 <command>
```

If there are no other devices connected over TCP/IP (namely emulators), you can shorten the command to:

```
      adb -e <command>
```

For example:

```
      adb -e logcat

      adb -e shell

      adb -e bugreport
```

Comment: Tis! But i follow this guide. And after "Enable Debugging over Bluetooth. You should see a tiny status summary appear under the option:" I see that: ` Host: disconnected Target: connected`

Comment: Yeah, I can't get the host to connect.  Not sure what the deal is.

Comment: Tap the home screen twice to bring up the Wear menu. :- It did not show any Wear menu on my Samsung tab

Comment: It was random luck for me. It wasn't working, I tried restarting the connection a few times and running the commands multiple times. Eventually it got connected.

Comment: Have you copied from Here[http://www.androiddocs.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html] or they have copied your answer? :D